# obj-c, how do I create a property and synthesize an NSUInteger?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm having some trouble using an NSUInteger, I've tried various things and googled, but not found the answer ?

I have... I also tried ... nonatomic, retain

```
@property (readwrite, assign) NSUInteger *anAmount;

@synthesize anAmount;
```

error: type of property 'anAmount' does not match type of ivar 'anAmount'

Also when I release it in dealloc I get a warning..

warning: invalid receiver type 'NSUInteger'

Comment: `NSUInteger` is not an object type, it's a primitive like `int` or `float`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `*` if you're not intending to use a pointer to an `NSUInteger` (which is a value type, and not a pointer type):

```
@property (readwrite, assign) NSUInteger anAmount;
```

And do not release it.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use NSNumber declaring and initializing below.  NSNumber provides some helper methods that may be of interest to you.

```
@property (readwrite, copy) NSNumber showMeTheMoney;

showMeTheMoney = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:1234567890];
```